# mysql_field_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "#";
$database = "book";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database) or die('There was a problem with connection!!');

$sql="select * from `book`;";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
if (!$result){
    die('Query cannot execute');
}

$row_cnt=$result->num_rows;
 $xml_dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
 $xml_dom->appendchild($xml_dom->createElement('result')) ;
 $xmlRoot=$xml_dom->documentElement;
while ($row = $row_cnt){
        $xml_row_node=$xml_dom->createElement('row');
        $i=0;
        for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_fields($result);$i++)
        {
            $xmlRow=$xml_dom->createElement(mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i)->name);  
            $xmlRowElement = $xml_dom->createTextNode($row[$i]);    
            $xmlRowElement->appendChild($xmlRowElement);
        }
        $xmlRoot->appendChild($xmlRowElement);
}
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml_dom->saveXML(); 
?>
```

there is the problem

```
$xmlRow=$xml_dom->createElement(mysql_field_name($result,$i));
```

and show me this error "mysql_field_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource"
when i check the manual of this method is use like i do(i use php 5.6)

and i try to get the name of the field like this:

```
$xmlRow=$xml_dom->createElement((string)mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i));
```

but i got this error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string 
 i try to convert the object that return that methodsmysqli_fetch_field_direct

Αny help will appreciate

Comment: You are mixing mysqli_query and mysql_field_name. You cant mix mysqli and mysql, use mysqli everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing `mysqli_query` and `mysql_field_name`.

You cant mix **mysqli** and **mysql**, use **mysqli** everywhere.

Use `mysqli_fetch_field_direct` and access it via `mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i)->name`

Comment: you are right i forgot that i cant mix mysqli with mysql i do that you write but i got that error now Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in the same line

Comment: @AndreasXatziosHadjiconstanti You probably have built a forever loop in your while + for construct, can you post all your updated code?